# Как в jsdoc в @param указать собственный тип MouseEvent?

Tags: javascript

Как в jsdoc в @param указать тип MouseEvent?
И HTMLElement DIV?

Делаю так:

```
/**
 * @param {MouseEvent} e
 */
 window.clickToButton = function(e) 
 {  
     console.dir(e);
 }

/**
 * @param {HTMLElement} d
 */
 window.clickToDiv = function(d)
 {
     console.dir(d);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html

И тут: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html

И конкретно по вашему случаю тут: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-typedef.html

```
/**
 * @typedef {object} MouseEvent
 * @typedef {object} HTMLElement
 */

/**
 * @param {MouseEvent} e
 */
window.clickToButton = function(e) {  
    console.dir(e);
}

/**
 * @param {HTMLElement} d
 */
window.clickToDiv = function(d) {
    console.dir(d);
}
```